# declaration vs definition in relation to Memory

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the distinction between declarations and definitions in C++. I've read various answers here and consulted the C++ Standard, but I'm still confused about a few points:

1. Some explanations suggest that definitions allocate memory to the variable, implying that if memory isn't allocated, it's considered a declaration. Is this always the case?
2. Which phase of the compilation process—Compiler or Linker—is primarily associated with declarations and definitions?

Here's a summary of my understanding so far:

**Declaration**: This informs the compiler about the existence of a variable or function, including its name and type, but doesn't specify memory allocation.

**Definition**: This not only declares the existence of a variable or function but also provides the implementation and how much memory a variable needs but it doesn't allocate memory unless it is used.

Given the following code snippet similar to what we've discussed in lectures:

```cpp
class Point { // declaration
public:
    int x; // declaration
    int y; // declaration
    void setPoint(int x, int y); // declaration
};

int main() {
    Point p1; // definition
};
```

My understanding is that everything in this code snippet should be considered a definition except for `void setPoint(int x, int y);`. However, I'm unsure about `int x;` because it seems that memory isn't allocated until an object is created. For instance, [my IDE (Clion) considers int x; a declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57K7L.png), which adds to my confusion.

Could someone please clarify how definitions are precisely associated with memory allocation? Additionally, I'd appreciate insights into the specific cases where memory is or isn't allocated for variables declared in classes or function bodies that haven't been invoked.

Comment: A declaration describes what a variable (in this case a class) looks like, and that will determine the memory size at runtime. But that will never allocate memory. Definitions (implementations) will result in code being generated which will take up some memory (your program needs to be stored somewhere)l. And then finally you instantiate types within your definition (implementation) which will allocate additional (runtime) memory. So I guess you mix up definition (implementation) with instances of types, like `p1`

Comment: So compiler generates (assembly code) from your definition, which the linker will link into a program (and it only uses those definitions actually used in your program). Then at runtim variables/instances are allocated on the stack or the heap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: no Iłya Bursov, that doesn't answer my question.
Pepijn Kramer, thanks for reply, "what a class looks like" as in body means it is a definition,but i think i understand now.  declarations are used by the compiler for type checking, name resolution, and generating appropriate code, they are like hints for compiler. actual implementation is in definitions and only they are included in the end executable program. and at runtime memory is allocated according to definitions and declarations don't exist at all at this phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations and definitions are about **names**, not necessarily about objects.

A somewhat simplified (hence, wrong) description of those terms is that a declaration tells the compiler that some name will be used in a particular way; a definition gives the compiler all the details of what that name means.

This is a declaration of the class `Point`:

```
class Point;
```

After that declaration the name `Point` can be used in ways that don't depend on its definition. `Point*` and `Point&` (pointer to `Point` and reference to `Point`, respectively) are probably the most common examples.

This is the definition of the class `Point`:

```
class Point {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    void setPoint(int x, int y);
};
```

Its two data members, `x` and `y`, are part of the definition. Those are neither declarations nor definitions. `void setPoint(int x, int y);` is a declaration of the member function `Point::setPoint`. Presumably, there's a definition somewhere that hasn't been shown.

This is a declaration of the object `p1`:

```
extern Point p1;
```

After that declaration the compiler knows that `p1` names an object of type `Point`, and the code can do any operations on `p1` that are valid for an object of type `Point`.

This is the definition of the object `p1`:

```
Point p1;
```

This tells the compiler "here it is".

Note that nothing in these descriptions mentions "memory". The definition of a class doesn't use memory; the definition of an object might mean "grab some memory for this thing", or it might mean "when the program gets here grab some memory for this thing".